# DRF: use to_representation to hide fields

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In my app, I want to hide absolute_url in the detail view and content in the list view. I always use different serializers and conditionals in view to achieve this goal. I wanted to know if it is a bad practice to use to_representation here.

serializers.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    absolute_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="full_name", read_only=True)

    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        slug_field="id",
    )

    def get_absolute_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        return request.build_absolute_uri(obj.slug)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        request = self.context.get("request")

        if request.parser_context.get("kwargs").get("slug"):

            rep.pop("absolute_url", None)
        else:
            rep.pop("content", None)

        rep["category"] = CategorySerializer(instance.category).data["name"]

        return rep

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data["author"] = User.objects.get(
            id=self.context.get("request").user.id
        )
        return super().create(validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "id",
            "author",
            "category",
            "title",
            "slug",
            "content",
            "status",
            "image",
            "absolute_url",
            "created_at",
            "updated_at",
            "published_at",
        ]
        read_only_fields = ["slug"]
```

views.py

```
class PostViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.select_related("author", "category").all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"
```

Comment: Can you share the full serializer and view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited my post, but I just want to know is it alright to use to_representation like this or not.